# Count(*) Timing Out on Large Table

Tags: mysql

Why would a simple query on the primary key be timing out on a table ~1 million records in MySQL?

I.e. Select Count(*) from table_name

Answer (score 0):

Innodb tables doesn't store a count of tables. Therefore `SELECT COUNT(*) ...` needs to read all the rows.

A rough estimate can be found using the [information_schema.tables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/tables-table.html).

Comment: Given that. What's the best way to analyse large data sets? Is it basically just to boost the hardware resources?

Comment: "analyse" is too broad. What specifically do you need? A buffer pool of sufficient size to include more of the index you are using help. Decent IO (low latency speed) will help

Comment: Just had a look and there is only 300 IOPS on the disk, then when monitoring the live IOPS using the command, iostat -dx 1, you can see the disk spike to >95% anytime even basic things are being done. Looks like a simple upgrade to better IOPS hard disk will solve the issue here.